# How to get the ids of the children using the parent id?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<div id="b">
  <div id="sss" class="card"><img src="img/sss" alt="sss"></div>
  <div id="ssa" class="card"><img src="img/sss" alt="sss"></div>
  <div id="ssb" class="card"><img src="img/sss" alt="sss"></div>
</div>
```

How do I get a list of IDs `"sss"`, `"ssa"`, `"ssb"` using `"board"`?

Comment: Loop over `document.getElementById("board").children`

Comment: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#board [id]'), ({ id }) => id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#board > div').forEach(dv=>console.log(dv.id))
```

```html
<div id="board">
  <div id="sss" class="card"><img src="img/sss" alt="sss"></div>
  <div id="ssa" class="card"><img src="img/sss" alt="sss"></div>
  <div id="ssb" class="card"><img src="img/sss" alt="sss"></div>
</div>
```